# how to hide jQuery bValidator errormessage

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using bValidator plugin on my website, and I'd like do the following:
After an error message shown, if I click in the input element (only text fields) hide the error message, and only shown again, if focus lost and it's still wrong. The second part is ok, it's just a parameter setting but  I can't get the first part to work.

I used onBeforeElementValidation like this:

```
    var options = {
            lang: 'hu',
            classNamePrefix: 'bvalidator_red_',
            validateOn: 'blur',
            errorValidateOn: 'null',
            onBeforeElementValidation : function(element){
                console.log(element);
                 $("#contact").data('bValidator').removeMsg(element);
            }
        }; 

$("#contact").bValidator(options);
```

I see in the console the input element, and the $("#contact") is the form selector.
If I want to use, the same option for  multiple forms, and I want to hide in every one of them the error message, how should I replace the $("#contact") selector?

Thanx

Comment: If this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/xwF9m/ then let me know I will set it as answer and you can accept its as answer for further reference

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#contact').focus(function(){
    $('selector-for-the-error-message').hide();
});
```

covers your first question.
Otherwise here an example i wrote (though with another plugin) that works exactly like you described: http://jsfiddle.net/ahaTs/1/

Your second question:
What about that:

```
$("#contact").bValidator(options);
$("#contact-two").bValidator(options);
```